# Python: how to reaplace each item in a list with a range of values?

Tags: python

I have the following list:

```
my_list = [22, 37, 48]
```

and I need to replace each item `x` in the list, with all the values in a range.
This is what I tried without having success:

```
threshold = 2
new_list = [y for y in range(x-threshold, x+threshold+1) for x in my_list]
```

because I get the following error:

```
Unresolved reference 'x'
```

but can't figure out what's wrong.

Comment: To solve your error, you'd have to interchange the order of your loops: `[y for x in my_list for y in range(x-threshold, x+threshold+1) ]`

Answer (score 0):

You are not making each element(`x`) an array. The way it is right now, it is kind of interpreted as a flattened version of nested for-loop. What you need is:

```
new_list = [[y for y in range(x-threshold, x+threshold+1)] for x in my_list]
```

Comment: This doesn't work, because it's clear OP wants a 1D array, so no, this is not what they need.

Comment: doesn't seem much wrong to me because in question user tried to work on list comprehension but user is not capable of doing it properly and stucked with namerror.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: "I need to replace each item x in the list, with all the values in a range." or replace every element with a `range(..)` -- sounds like an nested list to me.

Comment: But without any mention of "nested".

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you posted the desired output for your example. In this answer I've assumed you want the result [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50]:

```
outList = []
for x in my_list:
    outList += [y for y in range(x-threshold, x+threshold+1)]
```